# Is there a way to end a thenable chain?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

```
let textProcess = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let text
    try {
        // fetch text from the internet
        text = "str"
        resolve(text)
    } catch (e) {
        reject("failed to fetch!")
    }
})

textProcess.then(data => {
    let json
    try {
        json = JSON.parse(data)
    } catch (e) {
        console.error("failed to parse!")
        // ..........i want to end the whole process here, never go ahead
    }
}, e => {
    // try to fetch text from local chache
}).then(json => {
    // work on the json obj
}, e => {
    // if failed to fetch from local too, just let it go
})
```

Is there a way to end a thenable chain?

Look at the example above, I want to end the whole process when parsing is failed(the line preceeded with ".........."). But actually the last then will still be invoked though.

What is the proper and elegant way to achieve my goal?

Comment: First, consider adopting `.catch` instead of the second callback of `then` which can greatly simplify what you're doing and actually achieve what you need. What you're doing is considered an anti-pattern "The Overly Keen Error Handler" described in http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/

Comment: I think you just have to throw from inside. Please use `.catch(...)` as mentoined to profit from `throw`.

Comment: Does looking for the "json" in local cache return an object or string - i.e. does the cached copy also have to be parsed?

Comment: If you want errors to propagate, either (i) don't catch them, or if necessary (ii) catch them and re-throw.

Answer (score 1):

Your Promise usage involves quite a bit of sub-optimal patterns. Fixing them actually leads to what you're trying to achieve too.

```
textProcess.then(data => {
  // 1st anti-pattern fix
  // any error triggered here
  // also gets caught at the end catch
  return JSON.parse(data)
}).then(json => {
  // work on json obj
}).catch(e => {
  // 2nd anti-pattern fix
  // one catch for the whole thenable chain
  console.error("Failed to parse!", e)
})
```

This way, you properly leverage what Javascript Promise offers, and one simple `.catch` for what you need.

---

Edit - some explanations on involved Promise anti-patterns

The marked `1st anti-pattern` is about unnecessary nested `try..catch` block within `then`. Within it, you can return synchronously (even `undefined`), another Promise (both of these are `thenable`), or throw an Error (which would get caught by `catch`). Basically you don't need to explicitly catch it but let it "flow" through.

The `2nd anti-pattern` as mentioned is the fact that the second parameter -- reject handler of `then` is considered sub-optimal in most use cases. A Promise chain should be leveraging one `catch` to simplify the workflow.

However, in the rare event of the need to perform "early catch" and "resume", consider the following way, which is still a bit clearer than using two handlers for `then`:

```
textProcess.then(data => {
  return parser1(data)
}).catch(e => {
  console.log("First parser failed")
  // for example first parser failed
  return "fallback data"
}).then(data => {
  // process received data as "fallback data"
}).catch(e => {
  // always have a "last resort" catch at the end of the workflow
})
```

Comment: // always have a "last resort" catch at the end of the workflow. That means you need to determine where is the error from first. Maybe throw different subclass of Error in different place, or throw an error with different code is a good practice.

Comment: @zzzgoo sure, definitely good to have more enriched error information

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is no, there is no mechanism to terminate a promise chain in a `then` handler part-way down the chain. (A proposal for promise cancellation was made to the TC39 committee in 2016 but was subsequently withdrawn.)

Note that a **"promise chain"** often refers to the promise
returned by the **last** `then`, `catch` or `finally` call in a chain of single promise method calls concatenated together.

All calls to the promise methods listed above are made synchronously when code defining the chain is executed. After execution, all  promises in the chain have been created and all method calls in the chain called.

Since promises only have three states (pending, fulfilled and rejected), the best you can do is to arrange for "cancellation" to be sent down the rejection channel of linked promises and ignore it as required. (There is no standard "cancelled" rejection value to use).